# The group ring $\mathcal{O}_K [G]$ is a maximal $\mathcal{O}_K$ order in $K[G]$ if and only if $G$ is trivial

Tags: number-theory

Let $R$ denote a Noetherian integral domain with field of fractions $K$ with $K\neq R$. Let A be a finite dimensional $K$-algebra. An $R$-lattice in $A$ is a finitely generated $R$- submodule of $A$ such that $A=\textit{Span}_K(M)$. An $R$-lattice $M$ is said to be an $R$-order in $A$ if $M$ is a subring of $A$.

Here $K$ denotes a number field and $\mathcal{O}_K$ is the ring of integers. We know that $\mathcal{O}_K$ is a maximal order in $K$. Can anyone help me out to prove the converse part?

---